# Find and keep duplicated items in each column in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, janitor

Is there any way I can use some like tidyverse's add_count() %>% filter() or distinct() or alternatively janitor's get_dupes() to find and keep the **duplicated items of each column**. No need to compare items of different columns with each other, each column needs to be considered separately.

```
data1 <-tribble(
  ~colA, ~colB,
  "a",   1,
  "b",   1,
  "c",   2,
  "c",   3
)
```

Expected Output would be

```
colA colB

c   1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `map_dfc` which will map over the columns and return a data frame by column binding the outputs

```
library(tidyverse)
data1  %>% 
  map_dfc(~.x[duplicated(.x)])

# A tibble: 1 x 2
  colA   colB
  <chr> <dbl>
1 c         1
```

However this will result in unwanted behavior when each column has a different amount of duplicates due to recycling (when applying an operation to two vectors that requires them to be the same length - like column bind, R automatically repeats the shorter one, until it is long enough to match the longer one).

```
data1 <-tribble(
  ~colA, ~colB,
  "a",   1,
  "b",   1,
  "c",   2,
  "c",   3,
  "d",   1,
) 

data1  %>% 
  map_dfc( ~.x[duplicated(.x)])

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  colA   colB
  <chr> <dbl>
1 c         1
2 c         1
```

here `colA` has been recycled to match the length of `colB`. In such a case you are better off returning a list with `map`

```
data1  %>% 
  map( ~.x[duplicated(.x)])
#output
$colA
[1] "c"

$colB
[1] 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base`R

```
dupicatedList <- lapply(data1, function(columnValues) {
  unique(columnValues[duplicated(columnValues)])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option

```
> list2DF(Map(function(x) x[duplicated(x)], data1))
  colA colB
1    c    1
```